# Random Image when pressing a button in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcode11

I'm trying to make a random image appear on the screen, when I am pressing a button. I have three images which I want to be randomly shown, when I press the button. How do I do this?

Comment: Hi Jugap! Welcome to StackOverflow! This is a good question, but in the future, you should break it up into more specific parts with additional detail. For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26569698/creating-a-random-image-generator-with-swift?rq=1) is a duplicate of yours but is also more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using an Array you can use the .randomElement(). Here's a simple example using the symbols from SF Symbols.

```
struct RandomImage: View {

@State var random: String = ""

var body: some View {
    VStack {

        Image(systemName: random)

        Button(action: {
            self.random = chooseRandomImage()
        }) {
            Text("Another one!")
        }

    }


}
}

var images = ["sun.max.fill", "moon.fill", "star.fill"]

func chooseRandomImage() -> String {
    let array = images

    let result = array.randomElement()!

    return result
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It helped me very much